# Scroll to ID problem using BeTheme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble implementing the scroll to ID functionality properly using BeTheme in Wordpress.

I can get it to scroll to a section, but it does not scroll to the same postion consistently.

Sometimes it scrolls exactly to the top of the section (which is what I want it to do). But other times it misses the top of the section, sometimes above and other times below.

I tried using the section as the ID, some text at the top of the section as the ID, and even an image as the ID.  All result in the same landing position variability.

Is there a way to enter a fixed offset or exact target landing location with CSS?

Any ideas why it is not scrolling consistently and what I can do to make it scroll to the exact top of the section reliably?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code (see How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so we can help out.

Comment: This code initiates the link:
<p><a class="scroll" style="font-size: 30px;" href="#leib" data-font-size="30px"><u>Leib Kaufman</u></a></p>
The anchor ID (leib) is inserted in the Custom/ID field of the section to where I want to scroll.